# How to plot a matplotlib animation with pyscript?

Tags: python, matplotlib, web, matplotlib-animation, pyscript

I'm generating a website in the `pyscript` language from a code in `python` that generates animations of orbits of physical particles.

However, I'm having trouble plotting/generating the animations with `pyscript`.

Running the code locally, only the `plt.show()` hit to generate the animation. Already in Google Colab, I needed to change to `HTML(ani.to_jshtml())`. Using streamlit to generate a website as well, the animation generation worked with `components.html(ani2.to_jshtml(),height=800)`. However, generating a site outside the streamlit domain and using pyscript, I was not able to generate the animation. How can I do to generate it?

```
fig = plt.figure()
    
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_facecolor("black")
circle = Circle((0, 0), rg, color='dimgrey')
plt.gca().add_patch(circle)
plt.axis([- r_escala * 0.85 / u1, r_escala * 0.85 / u1, - r_escala * 0.85 / u1, r_escala * 0.85 / u1])
    
graph, = plt.plot([], [], 'k--', color="gold", markersize=3)
    
def animate(i):
   graph.set_data(x[:i], y[:i])
   return graph,
    
skipframes = int(len(uc) / 200)
if skipframes == 0:
   skipframes = 1
    
ani2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=range(0, len(x), skipframes), interval=10, blit=True, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I may be missing the intended goal? I'm not seeing why you need pyscript to do this? At least with your example. You can use `HTML(anim.to_jshtml()))` like you mention to generate the HTML and then build that produced HTML into the web page. I haven't separated it out, but [here](https://nbviewer.org/github/raphaelquast/jupyter_notebook_intro/blob/master/jupyter_nb_introduction.ipynb#pre-render-animations-and-export-to-HTML) you can see an animation previously generated as frames being runnable still inside a web page using the javascript based widget that `HTML(anim.to_jshtml()))` makes.

Comment: [Here](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/d862333d8eefb94a74a79022840680b1) is another example of a pre-generated plot that works in an otherwise 'static' rendering of a notebook as a web page. I know you don't want notebooks, but it is just showing it is possible in HTML without pyscript or Python around as long as you pre-generate the frames. In fact, you can also make **a portable HTML5-based video file that you can embed on HTML pages**. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70764815/8508004) you can see an example included in an SO post where you opt in to saving file with `anim.save()`.